# Can a protein go outside of nucleus after go inside with nuclear localization signal (NLS)

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, cas9

To make a protein (for example Cas9, GFP...) able to enter the nucleus, we need to add a NLS tag for it. So will it able to go outside the nucleus after get inside ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I need to add a NES (nuclear export signal) if I would like to make it able to export the nucleus : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_export_signal  .